# Move All Directories form EC2 windows extension to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

1) I have one Instance of EC2 (Windows) but i want to transfer all data from EC2 to S3 bucket.
2) I have only static files on EC2. Is my decision correct to transfer all data to S3 ?

- Please give answer step by step.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: By static files, you mean image files, pdfs etc ??

Comment: yes, collection of pdf,html,images .... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way to transfer files from EC2 to S3, I just install the cloudberry in my EC2 windows instance and then move files on S3 very easily.

Answer (score 0):

1) Transfer from EC2 (Windows) to S3 bucket.

> > Check out this command line tool : http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

2) I have only static files on EC2. Is my decision correct to transfer all data to S3 ?

> > Yes transferring them does make sense to me.